# Word for concept of degrees of definition

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for the concept that some words have different degrees of precision, and that misalignment or ambiguity over the intended precision easily leads to misunderstanding?

Some examples, but please note that I'm not trying to be particularly accurate with these definitions, but instead offered for purpose of drawing the point that there are two senses with differing levels of precision, and this ambiguity of precision if not addressed could lead to confusion/argument.

> In colloquial usage the word "`chemical`" generally refers to dangerous substances, more likely liquid, usually man-made, and differentiated from "natural"; while in scientific usage a "chemical" is pretty much anything made of atoms — arsenic is a naturally occuring chemical substance, as even is gold.

> A scientific "`theory`" is more narrowly defined than the colloquial usage, and particularly so as with a conspiracy "theory".

> Today, armour scholars define "`mail`" as it was defined in the Middle Ages — consisting of a "fabric" of interlocked metal rings that form a strong, flexible, mesh armour. (The word "mail" being derived through the Old English *mayle*, the French *maille*, and Italian *maglia*, from the Latin *macula*, which refers to the mesh of a net). This definition of mail was not the one used by Victorian scholars though. They used the word in a more general sense — to describe any sort of metallic body armour (i.e. "mail" is "armour", and thus a need to invent the term "chain mail"). [cribbed from [here](https://myarmoury.com/feature_mail.html)]

So, similar to how a synecdoche refers to parts/whole of a thing, but different in that here the differentiation is by precision. Also,  *polysemy* is too broad, as it encompasses *any* alternatives of definition and not specifically two senses which are similar in topic/direction but otherwise disagree in terms of precision.

(Doesn't *have* to be a single word)

---

Update: it would appear the closest sense has to do with Semantic Broadening and Semantic Narrowing.

Comment: I think you want *sense* (which of course has a regular meaning, and a special lexicographical one, as it should).

Comment: @KannE, can you provide references to support your claim that "chemical" is defined as being dangerous and not natural?

Comment: Chemical-free soup! Yay!

Comment: Does the accepted answer here answer your question? [Can a secondary definition violate / negate the first definition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547343/can-a-secondary-definition-violate-negate-the-first-definition/549873#549873). The concepts of **hypernymy/hyponymy**  and **polysemy** are covered comprehensively elsewhere. 'Dictionary definitions' are what you find in standard dictionaries (though there may be conflict even in general usage), while agencies, institutions etc may apply _precising_ or (when there is ensuing conflict) _stipulative definitions_. I know of ...

Comment: no term meaning 'degree of polysemy', 'total number of senses found in OED plus academic, business and legal works' or 'confusability rating'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! Not polysemy - that the word "chair" has multiple senses (both verbs and nouns) isn't the sense I was aiming at. Contranym is closer than polysemy, at least in that the two definitions are in conflict, and that careless usage can lead to confusion, but still not quite what I seek in that the definitions are opposites (the sense I seek is along the narrower/broader axis, but without the abstracting that hyponymy describes).

Comment: @KannE I used the word "colloquial" in the sense of "used in ordinary or familiar conversation; not formal or literary" — doesn't that fit "widely accepted definition"?

Comment: @PhilSweet Ooh, nice .. _sense_ itself has polysemy, of which it sounds like there are a particualar two that are mostly the same but differing in precision (i.e. general usage vs lexicographical). I am unfamiliar with this _lexicographic sense_ you mention, but it's led me to https://academic.oup.com/ijl/article-abstract/8/1/1/923391 as a starter. All a bit above my paygrade though. Thanks!

Comment: @KannE Who knows. Kids these days, constantly evolving the language. Bah humbug =)

Comment: The second-listed earlier thread contains '**semantic shift**' and the sub-category of _narrowing_.

Answer (score 0):

The lexicographers might step up, please.

The *degrees* you are looking for is the *description of the definitions* of words as their usage is enumerated in the dictionary. As you move from definition 1 to 5 and onward you will see the most common usage first and increasingly less common usages later. This is apparently not done in Merriam Webster

Usages primarily concern themselves with their audience. Advertisers use "chemical" to get a negative reaction from the majority of people. They even say it with a tone to show that it is not pleasant. Away from sales pitches a discussion about chemicals need have no negative interpretation.

"Theory" is a great example. Anyone defending the theory of Evolution is always pointing out that a proper theory is not described in the top two usages in the dictionary. There you see a theory as a general possibility not a scientific hypothesis.

Your degrees of precision are precisely those set forth ad seriatim in each definition. The name for such a listing out I cannot provide.

Comment: @KannE; That's why I come here. There is always something to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with finding such a word is that descriptions of definitions have no linear measurement. There is no continuum.

Those who prepare dictionaries can present definitions in whatever order they choose—for example, most common, earliest, or whatever. A word may be used as different parts of speech (noun, verb).  One word may have very different meanings. Consider, for example, “bow.”

Words that are uncommon in everyday speech may become more common, like social distancing, the use of which has become more common in the last year and changed in meaning in its most frequent use.

See Wikipedia on lexicography for more information on the theory and practice of making dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was unclear, I didn't mean to imply a continuum of senses and I also see in my doddering vagueness I've misled kind respondents down the broader _polysemy_ path too. I've added a 3rd example that might be helpful: "mail" is defined as a form of medieval armour being a mesh of metal links, but another definition has "mail" being armour of any form of fabrication (of which one particular form is termed "chain mail"). (The former definition is regarded by scholars as the correct one).

Comment: Scholars often choose more limited definitions, contriving another word for what they exclude. That’s the way language is. Some dictionaries distinguish, some don’t. Sometimes poisonous snakes include the venomous, but not in Zoology class.

Comment: @Erics Now you've given the example of 'mail', you've pinpointed the semantic shift known as  'semantic broadening' (narrowing can also occur), **certainly** (when the older sense is not extinguished, as with 'mail') giving rise to polysemy-with-hypernymy. This has been covered before. // Also note that scholars regard all common usages as 'the correct ones'.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth! "Semantic broadening/narrowing" will do for me nicely (lexicographic scholars maybe, but not scholars of medieval armour. Similarly no archeologist would consider "aliens" as a correct answer to "who built it", no matter how common the usage may be. But we're talking about two different things here - acknowledged usage, vs accurate definition. All good.)